# Repeat value from first now in a set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have retrieved a set of data from XML files, and now I want to parse them into distinct records to insert into a table that I have already defined by the distinct columns.

In this example, I have found there are 11 distinct columns from the source XML file. I have figured out the appropriate sort order of the columns so that they are always inserted into the table in the same order.

**Distinct table columns example**

```
 1  ad1_pk
 2  ad1_address1
 3  ad1_address2
 4  ad1_address3
 5  ad1_ctyfk
 6  ad1_postalcode
 7  ad1_active
 8  ad1_irstat
 9  ad1_irdata
 10 ad1_at1fk
 11 ad1_mk
```

With the following piece of code, I have "prepared the data to define the records":

```
SELECT TOP 100 t.drn,
z.ID,
null RecNum,
z.Name,
z.Value
--INTO zTempXMLDataConverted2
FROM dbo.zTempXMLDataConverted z
JOIN #tempSortOrder t ON t.node = z.Name
ORDER BY z.id,t.drn
```

... however, I have just one problem:  I can visually "see" the distinct records, but I do not know how to programatically determine each record (aka set the "RecNum" column to the appropriate record value.

So, this is ultimately what I want to see:

```
drn ------- ID ------ RecNum ------ Name -------------- Value
  1 ------   1 ------      1 ------ ad1_pk          --- 1
  2 ------   2 ------      1 ------ ad1_address1    --- P.O. Box 5036
  3 ------   3 ------      1 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------   4 ------      1 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------   5 ------      1 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 56
  6 ------   6 ------      1 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80155-5036
  7 ------   7 ------      1 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------   8 ------      1 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------   9 ------      1 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  10 ------      1 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  11 ------      2 ------ ad1_pk          --- 2
  2 ------  12 ------      2 ------ ad1_address1    --- 1871 S. Broadway
  3 ------  13 ------      2 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  14 ------      2 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  15 ------      2 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 1
  6 ------  16 ------      2 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80210
  7 ------  17 ------      2 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  18 ------      2 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  19 ------      2 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  20 ------      2 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  21 ------      3 ------ ad1_pk          --- 3
  2 ------  22 ------      3 ------ ad1_address1    --- 1575 W. 124th Avenue
  3 ------  23 ------      3 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  24 ------      3 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  25 ------      3 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 1
  6 ------  26 ------      3 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80234
  7 ------  27 ------      3 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  28 ------      3 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  29 ------      3 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  30 ------      3 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  31 ------      4 ------ ad1_pk          --- 4
  2 ------  32 ------      4 ------ ad1_address1    --- 6175 S. Forest Court
  3 ------  33 ------      4 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  34 ------      4 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  35 ------      4 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 101
  6 ------  36 ------      4 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80121
  7 ------  37 ------      4 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  38 ------      4 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  39 ------      4 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  40 ------      4 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  41 ------      5 ------ ad1_pk          --- 5
  2 ------  42 ------      5 ------ ad1_address1    --- 2000 E. County Line Rd., C-127
  3 ------  43 ------      5 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  44 ------      5 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  45 ------      5 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 87
  6 ------  46 ------      5 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80126
  7 ------  47 ------      5 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  48 ------      5 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  49 ------      5 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  50 ------      5 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  51 ------      6 ------ ad1_pk          --- 6
  2 ------  52 ------      6 ------ ad1_address1    --- 6911 S. University Blvd
  3 ------  53 ------      6 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  54 ------      6 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  55 ------      6 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 101
  6 ------  56 ------      6 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80122
  7 ------  57 ------      6 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  58 ------      6 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  59 ------      6 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  60 ------      6 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  61 ------      7 ------ ad1_pk          --- 7
  2 ------  62 ------      7 ------ ad1_address1    --- 215 Union Blvd., Suite 350
  3 ------  63 ------      7 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  64 ------      7 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  65 ------      7 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 96
  6 ------  66 ------      7 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80228
  7 ------  67 ------      7 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  68 ------      7 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  69 ------      7 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  70 ------      7 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  71 ------      8 ------ ad1_pk          --- 8
  2 ------  72 ------      8 ------ ad1_address1    --- 9700 E. Powers Avenue
  3 ------  73 ------      8 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  74 ------      8 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  75 ------      8 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 56
  6 ------  76 ------      8 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80111
  7 ------  77 ------      8 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  78 ------      8 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  79 ------      8 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  80 ------      8 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  81 ------      9 ------ ad1_pk          --- 9
  2 ------  82 ------      9 ------ ad1_address1    --- 650 S. Cherry Street, #420
  3 ------  83 ------      9 ------ ad1_address2    --- NULL
  4 ------  84 ------      9 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  85 ------      9 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 1
  6 ------  86 ------      9 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80222
  7 ------  87 ------      9 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  88 ------      9 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  89 ------      9 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------  90 ------      9 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
  1 ------  91 ------     10 ------ ad1_pk          --- 10
  2 ------  92 ------     10 ------ ad1_address1    --- 1001 17th St.
  3 ------  93 ------     10 ------ ad1_address2    --- Suite 1800
  4 ------  94 ------     10 ------ ad1_address3    --- NULL
  5 ------  95 ------     10 ------ ad1_ctyfk       --- 1
  6 ------  96 ------     10 ------ ad1_postalcode  --- 80202
  7 ------  97 ------     10 ------ ad1_active      --- Y
  8 ------  98 ------     10 ------ ad1_irstat      --- A
  9 ------  99 ------     10 ------ ad1_irdata      --- NULL
 10 ------ 100 ------     10 ------ ad1_at1fk       --- 1
```

AND THIS is ultimately what I want to get to:

```
ad1_pk --- ad1_address1 ------------------------ ad1_address2 ---- ad1_address3 ---- ad1_ctyfk ---- ad1_postalcode ---- ad1_active ---- ad1_irstat ---- ad1_irdata ---- ad1_at1fk
     1 --- P.O. Box 5036                     --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 56        ---- 80155-5036     ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     2 --- 1871 S. Broadway                  --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 1         ---- 80210          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     3 --- 1575 W. 124th Avenue              --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 1         ---- 80234          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     4 --- 6175 S. Forest Court              --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 101       ---- 80121          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     5 --- 2000 E. County Line Rd., C-127    --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 87        ---- 80126          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     6 --- 6911 S. University Blvd           --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 101       ---- 80122          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     7 --- 215 Union Blvd., Suite 350        --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 96        ---- 80228          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     8 --- 9700 E. Powers Avenue             --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 56        ---- 80111          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
     9 --- 650 S. Cherry Street, #420        --- NULL         ---- NULL         ---- 1         ---- 80222          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1         
    10 --- 1001 17th St.                     --- Suite 1800   ---- NULL         ---- 1         ---- 80202          ---- Y          ---- A          ---- NULL       ---- 1
```

Is this possible to do?

========================================================================

**EDIT: Possible solution to pivot table **

```
DECLARE @thisPK int
DECLARE @thisDRN INT
DECLARE @thisDRN2 INT
DECLARE @thisDRN3 int
DECLARE @thisIDStart INT
DECLARE @thisIDEnd INT
DECLARE @thisNumIDsAffected int

DECLARE @thisID int
DECLARE @thisColumn VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @thisValue VARCHAR(255)
--DECLARE @thisRecNum VARCHAR(MAX) = 1 -- the record indicator can be a char(1) or an int

DECLARE @distinctColumnsCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) [Cnt] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM dbo.zTempXMLDataConverted2) Step1 )
DECLARE @currentImportTable VARCHAR(MAX)='imaddad1'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLcolumnNames VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQLcolumnValues VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE recordGroupCursor CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY NumIDsAffected) drn,NumIDsAffected FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NumIDsAffected FROM #tempUpdateRanges) t1
    WHERE NumIDsAffected=9
)
OPEN recordGroupCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM recordGroupCursor INTO @thisDRN,@thisNumIDsAffected
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL='insert into '+@currentImportTable+' '
    SET @SQLcolumnNames='('
    SET @SQLcolumnValues=''

    DECLARE recordPullCursor CURSOR FOR (
        SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PK) drn,PK,IDStart,IDEnd FROM #tempUpdateRanges
        WHERE NumIDsAffected=@thisNumIDsAffected
    )
    OPEN recordPullCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM recordPullCursor INTO @thisDRN2,@thisPK,@thisIDStart,@thisIDEnd--,@thisNumIDsAffected
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0 --AND @thisDRN2<10
    BEGIN
        --if there happens to be any anomalies in the data, where there are more columns present in a record
        --then the distinct column count, then only get the number of columns that can fit into the table
        IF @thisNumIDsAffected>@distinctColumnsCount BEGIN
            SET @thisIDEnd = @thisIDStart+@distinctColumnsCount
        END
        SET @SQLcolumnValues=@SQLcolumnValues
        DECLARE recordDetailsCursor CURSOR FOR (
            SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID) drn,ID,Name,Value FROM dbo.zTempXMLDataConverted2 WHERE ID between @thisIDStart AND @thisIDEnd
        )
        OPEN recordDetailsCursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM recordDetailsCursor INTO @thisDRN3,@thisID,@thisColumn,@thisValue
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
            IF @thisDRN2=1 BEGIN
                SET @SQLcolumnNames += @thisColumn+','+CHAR(10)
            END
            SET @SQLcolumnValues += ''''+ISNULL(@thisValue,'')+''','
            FETCH NEXT FROM recordDetailsCursor INTO @thisDRN3,@thisID,@thisColumn,@thisValue
        END
        CLOSE recordDetailsCursor
        DEALLOCATE recordDetailsCursor
        SET @SQLcolumnValues = LEFT(@SQLcolumnValues,LEN(@SQLcolumnValues)-1)+' UNION ALL '+CHAR(10)+'SELECT '
        --PRINT @SQLcolumnValues
        FETCH NEXT FROM recordPullCursor INTO @thisDRN2,@thisPK,@thisIDStart,@thisIDEnd--,@thisNumIDsAffected
    END
    CLOSE recordPullCursor
    DEALLOCATE recordPullCursor

    SET @SQL += LEFT(@SQLcolumnNames,LEN(@SQLcolumnNames)-2)+') '+CHAR(10)+'SELECT '+LEFT(@SQLcolumnValues,LEN(@SQLcolumnValues)-11)
    BEGIN TRY
        --SET @SQLerrors=''
        --PRINT @SQL
        EXEC (@SQL)
        --RAISERROR('  Record %10i Processed',0,1,@thisPK) WITH NOWAIT
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --SET @SQLerrors = 'ERROR!: Creating table '+@currentImportTable+CHAR(10)+ERROR_MESSAGE()
        PRINT @SQL+CHAR(10)+ERROR_MESSAGE()
        --GOTO EARLY_END
    END CATCH
    FETCH NEXT FROM recordGroupCursor INTO @thisDRN,@thisNumIDsAffected
END
CLOSE recordGroupCursor
DEALLOCATE recordGroupCursor

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Comment: So you have 2 problems, get the recnum and pivoting the data?

Comment: I have got a slight solution to pivot the data, but it involves nested cursors (see edit above)

Comment: my this answer could help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31069954/4070011

Comment: What's the point of recnum? You don't have it in your final result at all.

Comment: can't see your original xml data but it seems you should be able to parse it directly to get the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the RecNum to change when drn starts over, you can use this kind logic:

```
select
  drn, id,
  dense_rank() over (order by GRP) as RecNum
from (
  select drn, id, id-drn as GRP from table1
) X
order by id
```

This will use the difference between drn and id to determine to which "group" the row belongs and uses that in dense rank to number the rows. You can check this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ee2e/3). This assumes there's no jumps / gaps or anything weird in your data, otherwise the RecNum will jump too.

Based on the edit I would assume your final columns are not fixed, so you'll need to do a dynamic pivot. There's a lot of examples for that in SO, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query).